# Recommendations on keeping a Flash site operational (for defined set of users under our control) after 12/31/2020

Tags: flash, air, webbrowser-control

In brief, our company has an administrative site that contains a Flash component, and we will not be able to retire it by the end of the year when all the browser companies stop supporting Flash, so we're looking at our options to keep it operational for the limited number of users who need access.

Let's get this out of the day: Yes, Flash is bad and we should all be glad that it's finally going to be dead. Any site that still relies on it should have been updated or retired long ago. It should be embarrassing for a company to find itself in this situation. Running Flash past EOL introduces major security concerns. Okay, fine. Granted. All our customer-facing stuff is off Flash but this one piece couldn't be done in time. Moving on . . .

Our goal is to be able to let these users continue to use this Flash-dependent site after the first round of browser updates in 2021 kill Flash completely. As I said it's a limited number of users, all running Windows, and we can mandate any solution we want, e.g. downloading and installing a dedicated AIR app, writing a .NET app with a WebBrowser control that only loads this one site, or something else.

The bar for success is that, after browser updates forever break Flash on these machines, the users can still use this site as they do today, including the one or two portions of it that use Flash. In case it makes a difference, there's no video and it's not a game site where the whole window is Flash, it's an HTML single-page app with some Flash content in places.

If someone out there has found themselves in a similar boat and is a bit further along in finding and validating a solution, please share!

Thanks!

-joel

Comment: Is running it as a site in a browser mandatory? Unless you have some JavaScript environment in the page, you might go for a simple Desktop AIR app that loads your remote app via HTTP.

Comment: @Organis Thanks for responding. If I understand your question correctly, it's an interactive web app so there's definitely javascript required for it to function.

Comment: Well, then, this: https://services.harman.com/partners/adobe (look into **PACKAGED BROWSER SOLUTION** section).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I messaged them and will post what I find out. I'll leave the question open for now in case others have thoughts. Since you seem to have some familiarity with that approach, do you know if it's something most desktop development teams could do or do we really need a subject-matter expert like them? The last thing I want is to *think* we've solved the problem and then have 2021 . . . start poorly. But if they're a million bucks, booked solid, etc. I want to know our options.

Comment: Hmmm, how to put this... I'm not familiar with that approach like at all. I'm just a dinosaur Flash guru who happened to know the future of Flash (well, some of it).

Comment: @Organis refers to himself as a dinosaur, but he is the T-Rex of Flash developers ;)

Comment: @crooksy88 No, no, I'm totally a kiwi (I hope you are aware that birds are actually the last dinosaurs alive) bird: old, sad, cannot fly (never could), and has its reproduction consume a grand part of its existence: https://www.audubon.org/news/why-kiwis-egg-so-big

Comment: @JoelP. Have you manged to find out what there approach is ?